# ñ no devuelta en metodo get de Java

Tags: java, mysql, api

estoy haciendo una api con java(en eclipse) y mysql, el problema es que el manejadorPalabras(maneja todas las palabras que recibe de la BD)
public ArrayList obtenerPalabra(String categoria) {

```
    ManejadorBD manejbd = new ManejadorBD();
     char letras[] =  {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z',};
    ArrayList<Palabra> palabras = new ArrayList<Palabra>();
    
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i<letras.length; i++) {
        Palabra palabraActual = manejbd.obtenerPalabra(categoria, letras[i]);
        palabras.add(palabraActual);
    }
    
    return palabras;
}
```

despues, tengo un manejador de la base de datos que me sirve para llamar a la base de datos y las columnas de las tablas

```
public Palabra obtenerPalabra(String categoria, char letra) {
        DBConf dbconf = new DBConf();
        Connection con = dbconf.conectarMySQL();
        
        ArrayList<Palabra> palabras = new ArrayList<Palabra>();
        Palabra pal = null;

        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();


            // HACIENDO QUERY
            String query2 = "SELECT * FROM Palabra WHERE nombreCat = '"+ categoria +"' and letra='" + letra + "'";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query2);
            
            
            boolean salimo = false;
            int codigoPal=0;
            
            while(rs.next() && !salimo) {
                boolean enUso = rs.getBoolean("estaEnUso");
                
                if(enUso == false) {
                     codigoPal = rs.getInt("codigoPal");
                    int codigoEnJuego = rs.getInt("codigoEnJuego");
                    char let = rs.getString("letra").charAt(0);
                    String definicion = rs.getString("definicion");
                    String palabra = rs.getString("palabra");
                    boolean empiezaPor = rs.getBoolean("empieza");
                    
                    
                    pal = new Palabra(codigoPal, codigoEnJuego, let, definicion, palabra, empiezaPor, enUso, 0, 0);
                    palabras.add(pal);
                    salimo = true;
                }
            }
            
            if(salimo = true) {
                //Mandar un update para la palabra que obtuvimos y pasarle el estado de enUso a true
                String query3 = "UPDATE Palabra SET estaEnUso = true WHERE codigoPal = '" + codigoPal +"'";
            } else {
                // PAsas todas las palabras con esa letra y esa categoria a enUso = false
                // Sacas la primera y la dejas en true
                String query4 = "UPDATE Palabra SET estaEnUSo = false";
                String query5 = "UPDATE Palabra SET estaEnUSo = false WHERE codigoPal = 0";
            }
            
            
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
        return pal;
                    
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el problema es que no me trae la ñ, cuando hago el get en postman(programa para testear endpoints) me vuelve la ñ duplicada, y la ñ esta en la base de datos por si lo preguntan.

Comment: Diría más bien que te toma la **ñ** como **n** (por eso te trae la **n** dos veces). ¿Está bien el _encoding_?

Comment: al final era algo de mysql, me ayudaron en la respuesta de abajo, aunque no se que es el encoding, pero gracias igualmente, es muy lindo que se tomen tiempo para ayudar a los devs que aun estan aprendiendo

Comment: Te doy un ejemplo para que busques más info: UTF-8 es un formato de codificación de caracteres (_character encoding_). Y lo que te mencionaron en la respuesta: busca acerca de cotejamiento (_collation_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema viene del cotejamiento de la Base de datos, que no coge bien los caracteres con acentos o eñes. Tenemos que indicar a la Base de datos el tipo de codificación que estamos usando.

Comprueba si tu Base de datos tiene cotejamiento **utf_unicode_ci.**

Y para asegurarte del todo, a la hora de crear tablas puedes incluir  **CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci** en cada atributo varchar.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias, si funciono, pense que era un error de java pero era de mysql